# MFC: Can't ExtractIcon() or create a CBitmap from handle returned by GetImageInfo() on an image list created by CListCtrl::CreateDragImage

Tags: winapi, drag-and-drop, mfc

I wanted to use the `CListCtrl::CreateDragImage()` to create the image used as the source of a drag outside of the program itself.  I then wanted to take it and create a bitmap for `IDragSourceHelper::InitializeFromBitmap`.  However, I can't get the bitmap from the CImageList created;

I confirmed the iItem should be fine.  I tried two different ways within the `OnBeingdrag(NMHDR* pnmhdr, LRESULT* presult)` function:

Using `ExtractIcon()`:

```
CListCtrl &listctrl=GetListCtrl();
CPoint pt1(0, 0);
CImageList *imagelist=listctrl.CreateDragImage(pnmlistview->iItem, &pt1);
if (imagelist) { 
  // created with GetImageCount()==1
  HICON hicon=imagelist->ExtractIcon(0);
  if (hicon!=NULL) {
    /** NEVER GETS HERE **/
```

Using `GetImageInfo()`:

```
CListCtrl &listctrl=GetListCtrl();
CPoint pt1(0, 0);
CImageList *imagelist=listctrl.CreateDragImage(pnmlistview->iItem, &pt1);
if (imagelist) {
  // created with GetImageCount()==1
  IMAGEINFO imginfo;
  if (imagelist->GetImageInfo(0, &imginfo)) {
    // information is received - create bitmap
    CBitmap bmp;
    if (bmp.FromHandle(imginfo.hbmImage)!=NULL) {
       // ** NEVER GETS HERE **
```

For kicks I tried:

```
  CPoint pt1(0,0);
  CPoint pt2;
  CImageList *imglist=imagelist->GetDragImage(&pt1, &pt2);
  // ** imglist is NULL **
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Turns out I have direct access to the CImageList and this works (plus fixing to use the pointer returned FromBitmap).

```
  IMAGEINFO imginfo;
  if (m_ImageList.GetImageInfo(pnmlistview->iItem, &imginfo)) {
    // create bitmap
    CBitmap *bmp=CBitmap::FromHandle(imginfo.hbmImage);
    if (bmp->GetSafeHandle()!=NULL) {
```

TIA!!

Comment: Does your listview do custom drawing? I have a feeling GetDragImage is broken in that case.

Comment: I don't see anything that suggests it's owner drawn.   The Create is overridden to add additional styles `LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS|LVS_ALIGNTOP|LVS_ICON|LVS_AUTOARRANGE` and nothing in the message maps for painting or drawing (only printing).

Comment: I edited the original to also use the actual CImageList assigned to the CListCtrl.